# Logging into Azure DevOps services, I have three users, all the same, to select from — why?

Tags: azure-devops

After signing-in to Azure DevOps Services, on the left pane I can select from three different accounts:

[image: Azure DevOps Services launch screen]

All these accounts are pointing to my name and my e-mail address.

What's there reason I have three different accounts? How can I delete the redundant ones? Is there any documentation available, explaining this odd situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aex signin page (https://aex.dev.azure.com/) lists the Organizations your account has some access to.

You should be able to see the list of organizations after logging into the MyAccount page with your Microsoft account, and you can leave the Organizations you don't need:

https://myaccount.microsoft.com/organizations

---

These are **separate** from Azure DevOps Organizations, despite having the same name. It's sort of organized like: Microsoft Account > Organization (Azure tenant) > Azure DevOps Organization > Project

You can skip straight to your DevOps project by using a link like:

https://dev.azure.com/MyAzureDevOpsOrganization/MyAzureDevOpsProject

Comment: Thank you for trying to help! I have to admit I also contacted Microsoft Support with this question. They suggest [these items are "tenants", or "directories"](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Logging-into-Azure-DevOps-services-I-ha/10466537). I was able find the second tenant now, yet I still wonder what the third entry "Microsoft account" is.

Comment: @AxD If it's not another tenant, do you have a "personal" account (vs work/school accounts) with the same email address? Any tenants should be listed in the MyAccount page I linked - maybe you have one with "Microsoft Account" as the display name?